# Active / unactive classes for good icon usage with CSS

Tags: css

I'm doing a website where I define icons in the CSS and then I use it in HTML with a simple classes, for example this is for the dashboard:

```
.icon {padding-left: 22px;line-height: 16px;}

.icon-dashboard {background: url("/img/icons/dashboard_off.png") no-repeat}
.icon-dashboard:hover, .icon-dashboard:active {background: url("/img/icons/dashboard_on.png") no-repeat}
```

Then I can use it:

```
<a class="icon icon-dashboard" href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
```

Now I have an `anchor` with a icon that, when I hover takes color (off=b&w, on=color). That's ok, all my menu is by default in off state and when hovered to on state.

The problem: this icons are for display a submenu when click that, by default, is hidden. When I click on a `anchor` with `.icon` the next `<div />` is showed. That's ok, but then when I move throw this `<div />` the anchor, of course, is in off state.

I need to add a class, or something, that mantains the icon of the `anchor` in "on" state but I want to know if is possible to do it without rewriting the class like `icon-dashboard-active`. One of the main reasons is because I want to add in javascript, when clicked, a class that automatically converts to "on" state.

I wish this is better explained.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make sure to close your `background` properties...

Comment: Also, why not do `.icon-dashboard{padding-left: 22px;line-height: 16px; background:...;}`? It does the same as what you have now and cuts down on a class as well.

Comment: @Samir: I'll try to explain better, in english is not my main language... ;(

Comment: @Andrew because I've like 50 icons, and "padding-left: 22px;line-height: 16px;" = 38 chars * 50 = 1900. If I use 50 icons on a page, icon=4chars * 50 = 200. That's the reason.

Comment: @Samir Adel: is better now? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @udexter Ah okay, I didn't realize that. Thanks for the update! I'll try and find a way to solve your problem.

Comment: Could you please post a more of your html i.e. the menu and submenu. And maybe even make a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS

```
.icon {
    padding-left: 22px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.icon.dashboard{
    background-image: url("/img/icons/dashboard_off.png"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.icon.dashboard:hover, 
.icon.dashboard:active,
.icon.dashboard.active{
    background-image: url("/img/icons/dashboard_on.png")
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="icon dashboard" href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
```

This is how you would do a good inheritance CSS styling.

If you add the class `active` to the anchor, it will stay on the forced "on" state until you remove the class.

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/243JD/)